# Can Someone Help Me Create a Custom Feature Map with the Latest Version of Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming, quantum-state, variational-quantum-algorithms

I am trying to create a custom feature map that I can use as input to the VQC classifier for classification purposes. I attempted to follow a GitHub repository: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/master/machine_learning/custom_feature_map.ipynb.
But the author was using an older version of Qiskit. As a result, I was unable to locate the FeatureMap library due to the Aqua library's deprecation. Currently, I am using Qiskit version 0.42.

This is the custom feature map that I attempted to use. During my search for a solution, I discovered that I could pass the QuantumCircuit to inherit from. since I was unable to access the FeatureMap library in the newer version :

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

class CustomFeatureMap(QuantumCircuit):
    def __init__(self, feature_dimension, data):
        super().__init__(feature_dimension)
        
        # Print a message to see if this method is being called
        print("Initializing custom feature map")
        
        for sample in data:
            for i in range(feature_dimension):
                # Use the data to determine which gates to apply
                if sample[i] == 1:
                    control_qubit = i % feature_dimension
                    target_qubit = (i + 1) % feature_dimension
                    self.cx(control_qubit, target_qubit)
                    
                    # Print information about the CX gate being applied
                    print(f"Applying CX gate to qubits {control_qubit} and {target_qubit}")
```

When I attempted to pass the custom feature map to initialize the VQC, I received an error message. To ensure that there was not a problem with the shape of the train data or the number of qubits that was passed to the VQC, I tried to use the built-in feature maps. The VQC worked successfully with the built-in feature maps, leading me to conclude that the issue lay with the custom feature map. However, I was unable to determine the specific source of the problem, so I am seeking assistance. This is the error message that I encountered:

```
Initializing custom feature map
<ipython-input-15-9d2987c0f910>:12: DeprecationWarning: The quantum_instance argument is deprecated as of version 0.5.0 and will be removed no sooner than 3 months after the release. Instead use the sampler argument.
  vqc_classifier = VQC(feature_map=feature_map,
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QiskitMachineLearningError                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     15                      quantum_instance=quantum_instance)
     16 
---> 17 vqc_classifier.fit(train_data, train_labels)

c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit_machine_learning\algorithms\trainable_model.py in fit(self, X, y)
    197             self._fit_result = None
    198 
--> 199         self._fit_result = self._fit_internal(X, y)
    200         return self
    201 

c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit_machine_learning\algorithms\classifiers\vqc.py in _fit_internal(self, X, y)
    191 
    192         function = self._create_objective(X, y)
--> 193         return self._minimize(function)
    194 
    195     def _get_interpret(self, num_classes: int):

c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit_machine_learning\algorithms\trainable_model.py in _minimize(self, function)
    293             )
    294         else:
--> 295             optimizer_result = self._optimizer.minimize(
...
--> 132             raise QiskitMachineLearningError(
    133                 f"Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension "
    134                 f"is not equal to the number of inputs: "

QiskitMachineLearningError: 'Input data has incorrect shape, last dimension is not equal to the number of inputs: 0, but got: 8.'
```